# iPhone & iPad orientation (universal app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to show different orientation depending on device.

On iPhone I want to allow portrait orientation, on iPad I want to allow landscapeleft orientation.

Is that possible?

I tried

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    }
    else {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, so did you try your code? Didn't it work? Is it in your main view controller?

Comment: your code will work fine try it out. Its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted does the job. However you need to add Supported Device Orientations to Info.plist. The easiest way to do this is to select appriopriate settings in  `Project->Target->Summary->Supported Device Orientations` section.

Comment: The point is: 

In my project-target-summary-supported (etc) I enable portrait for iphone and landscapeleft for ipad.

And, then, in project > target > info, in > Supported device orientations too.

Then, in my AppDelegate I write the code above.

After doing this changes, my tabbar is still in the same portrait position.

Comment: @Bernat: That's why I asked whether you've put in your main view controller. The app delegate is the wrong location for that method.

Comment: Should I put it in every viewController?

Comment: @Bernat yes, you should put this in every viewController

Comment: I tried it (put this code in every view controller used in the tabBar app) and TabBar still in wrong position. I'm doing something wrong... mmm

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your app delegate: (Swift)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight.rawValue)
    }
}
```